# Why does my profile picture randomly change?

Tags: support

Title says it all. Today I logged in to find my picture had changed to an ugly green and white.

Comment: Do you use Gravatar or have you uploaded to SE directly?

Comment: @Tim - Neither. This is the default icon.

Comment: I mean which what did it change from - your gravatar or an upload?

Comment: @Tim - I don't know what you're talking about. Before it was purple and white with a different pattern.

Comment: So you changed your email address on this site?

Comment: @Tim - No I did not.

Comment: [does this help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106023/keep-a-users-identicon-profile-picture-consistent?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: @Zanna could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106023/keep-a-users-identicon-profile-picture-consistent?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> your identicon is based on a hash of your *last known* IP address

if you didn't enter your email address on your profile.

So, if you haven't put your email address on your profile and you logged in from a different IP address, your identicon would change... Maybe this is the explanation in your case.